# NGINX ignore bad certificate and configuration and just run?

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns

We have an app that uploads automatically generated SSL certificate to our NGINX load balancers. One time the we had this issue that a "bad certificate" got uploaded and then a automated `nginx reload` is thereafter executed, our server went offline for a while causing DNS issues (DNS not found) for our server domain. Causing a huge downtime to our clients.

However it is a feature / function in our application to allow apps to upload SSL cerficate and our backend server installs it automatically, is there a way to tell to ignore bad NGINX `conf` files and `crt/key`'s altogether? *Looking at the before logs I can remember that I saw something like SSL handshake error before the incident.*

Here's how our main `nginx-jelastic.conf` looks like:

```
######## HTTP SECTION PROTOTYPE ########
http {
    server_tokens off ;
    ### other settings hidden for simplicity
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
######## TCP SECTION PROTOTYPE ########
```

So what I am thinking if it's possible for nginx to just ignore all bad NGINX conf files that is located there. Here's a sample of what gets uploaded in the `conf.d` folder:

#

## www.example-domain.com HTTPS server configuration

#

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example-domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /var/lib/nginx/ssl/www.example-domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/nginx/ssl/www.example-domain.com.key;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;
    proxy_temp_path /var/nginx/tmp/;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location / {
        set $upstream_name common;
        include conf.d/ssl.upstreams.inc;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream_name;
        proxy_next_upstream error;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-URI $uri;
        proxy_set_header X-ARGS $args;
        proxy_set_header Refer $http_refer;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

For some reason the certificate and key indicated in the configuration could be wrong, that that is going to wreck the nginx server and since our domain is pointed to this server via A record, it us a total disaster if the nginx fails as DNS issues happens and it could take 24-48 hours for DNS to get back.

Comment: It is unclear what your web server has to do with DNS. Resolving a name to an A record at DNS level is independent if a web server is running or not - and in fact DNS resolution needs to web server anywhere at all. Apart from that, why don't you simply test if the configuration is correct before restarting nginx, i.e. use `nginx -t` ?

Comment: @steffen-ullrich Yeah, this is what I am thinking also but our big incident happened last night and by morning all our Web server behind Nginx is not accessible, since that night the nginx did not run due to configuration error, the problem was that in Asia around 8am the web server is not accessible following in the USA, we fixed the nginx by the same hour and it took like til afternoon for the web server is accesible, so I assumed that DNS servers cached something wrong?

Comment: I don't know your setup but maybe there is some job at your site which checks the availability of servers and reconfigures  the DNS if a server is considered broken. Anyway - it is a bad idea to expect nginx to work with a broken config because this essentially means undefined behavior. Instead you should make sure that the config is not broken in the first place, i.e. check config before you load it, check availability after you've loaded it and roll back to old config if something failed. This gives you a defined behavior instead of "pick what you like from the config and ignore the rest".

Comment: Here is our process, app gets certificate from users, uploads to the the nginx server via write file api (writes the crt, key and the chained nginx config file) then do a nginx reload command, so what you are referring before nginx reload check the config? will nginx be able to pick up the added files in the /var/lib/nginx/con.d/ folder without reloading first?

Comment: I referred to `nginx -t` command which I've already mentioned in the first comment. This essentially parses all configuration but does not restart/reload nginx.

Comment: I am seeing a similar phenomenon: nginx silently ignores the ssl directive and serves the site via HTTP.

Comment: strongly disagree with @SteffenUllrich on this; nginx needs to be able to ignore config blocks that fail. Preferably this could be a setting in the root nginx.conf file. There's no reason for this to cause undefined behavior, merely the entire block should be pass/fail --OR-- nginx should not outright tank because of missing certificate file, serving a default generic cert if needed. `nginx -t` is not sufficient to avoid race conditions in many common platform setups